# 32-bit registers in real mode and dereferencing

Tags: assembly, real-mode

I'm writing some assembly for MBR (real mode). I know that in real mode you can't use the 32-bit registers, only the 16-bit ones.

I wrote this code which relies on a `print_char` function.

```
    mov ecx, MSG
write:
    mov al, [ecx]
    cmp al, 0x0
    je end_print
    call print_char
    inc cx
    jmp write
end_print:
    ret
MSG: db 'Hi!', 0xd, 0xa, 0x0
```

This code doesn't compile due to the reason:

```
error: invalid effective address
```

I use

```
nasm -f bin -o out src.s
```

When I change the register name to `ecx`, the code starts to compile, and surprisingly, works.

Why does my code using 32-bit registers work in real mode and why does using 16-bit registers not?

Comment: You can use 32 bit registers on a 32 bit cpu, real mode or not. But if you use 16 bit addressing, you must use the valid modes, and `[cx]` isn't one.

Comment: Why downvotes??

Comment: I didn't downvote but my guess is they felt _"it doesn't show any research effort"_. You could have looked up the addressing modes in the intel manual yourself, in particular, _"The address-size override prefix (67H) allows programs to switch between 16- and 32-bit addressing. Either size can be the default; the prefix selects the non-default size."_

Comment: I didn't really know what to search for. Searching for *invalid effective address* didn't yield anything useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The x86 ISA supports a number of addressing modes. There are two sets of addressing modes, one for 16 bit mode and one for 32 bit mode.

In 32 bit mode, you can use indexed addressing with any register and the three-part SIB addressing.

In 16 bit mode, only the following addressing modes exist (each with optional displacement):

```
BX + disp
BX + SI + disp
BX + DI + disp
BP + disp
BP + SI + disp
BP + DI + disp
SI + disp
DI + disp
disp
```

Note how `cx` isn't available as an index register.

What you can do to get around this problem is to use a 32 bit addressing mode in 16 bit mode. This is done by specifying `ecx` as an index register as you did.

Comment: Why can I use 32-bit addressing while being in 16-bit mode? If the processor puts extra, 16-bit constraints on itself, it should not allow it.

Comment: There is no reason to limit this. It's backward compatible and just gives you more options. Note that you can similarly use 16 bit addressing in 32 bit mode, and 32 bit addressing in 64 bit mode (but only the last one is typically useful).

Comment: @marmistrz Basically, 32 bit mode was designed such that 16 bit programs can use 32 bit instructions as needed. This is done through two prefixes 66 and 67 which switch data and addressing with to 32 bit mode. In 32 bit mode, the meaning of these prefixes is simply reversed.